# How to create a relationship between two eloquent models

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

I have two Models: Users and Appointments

```
class Appointments extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = [
        'business_id',
        'user_id',
        'subject',
        'description',
        'status',
        'phone_number',
        'start_appointment',
        'end_appointment',
    ];

class User extends Authenticatable
{
protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'email',
        'password',
        'card_id',
        'assigned_to',
        'user_type',
        'password_changed_at',
    ];
}
```

My relationship in Appointment Model:

```
public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class); 
    }
```

user_id and business_id correspond to user_id on the user model.
I want to be able to do something like this:

```
 App\Models\Appointments {#5029
     id: 1,
     business_id: 24,
     status: "in_progress",
     subject: "Minima similique aspernatur temporibus corporis libero aut voluptatibus.",
     description: "The players all played at once set to work, and very soon had to kneel down on the Duchess's cook.",
     phone_number: "205-565-2817",
     user_id: 27,
     start_appointment: "2022-10-22 18:38:17",
     end_appointment: "2022-10-22 19:08:17",
     created_at: "2022-10-10 16:39:53",
     updated_at: "2022-10-10 16:39:53",
     user: App\Models\User {#5050
       id: 27,
       name: "Susan Bosco",
       email: "kemmer.sadye@example.com",
       card_id: "6163819953",
       email_verified_at: "2022-10-10 11:41:57",
       #password: "$2y$10$92IXUNpkjO0rOQ5byMi.Ye4oKoEa3Ro9llC/.og/at2.uheWG/igi",
       #two_factor_secret: null,
       #two_factor_recovery_codes: null,
       #remember_token: "zTnSUsbrEL",
       current_team_id: null,
       profile_photo_path: null,
       created_at: "2022-10-10 11:41:57",
       updated_at: "2022-10-10 11:41:57",
       assigned_to: null,
       doctor_type: null,
       user_type: 0,
       password_changed_at: "2022-10-10 11:41:57",
       deleted_at: null,
       +profile_photo_url: "https://ui-avatars.com/api/?name=S+B&color=7F9CF5&background=EBF4FF",
     },
App\Models\User {#5059
         id: 24,
         name: "Dr. Floyd O'Keefe MD",
         email: "vupton@example.net",
         card_id: "1892324633",
         email_verified_at: "2022-10-10 11:41:57",
         #password: "$2y$10$92IXUNpkjO0rOQ5byMi.Ye4oKoEa3Ro9llC/.og/at2.uheWG/igi",
         #two_factor_secret: null,
         #two_factor_recovery_codes: null,
         #remember_token: "Dxb9oivJ7H",
         current_team_id: null,
         profile_photo_path: null,
         created_at: "2022-10-10 11:41:57",
         updated_at: "2022-10-10 11:48:55",
         assigned_to: 28,
         doctor_type: null,
         user_type: 2,
         password_changed_at: "2022-10-10 11:41:57",
         deleted_at: null,
       },
```

```
$appointments->client_name;
$appointments->business_name
```

This i how i get the Appointments

```
  public function getAppointmetns(){
        $doctors = User::where([['user_type',2],['assigned_to',auth()->id()]])->pluck('id');
        return Appointments::with(['user'])->whereIn('business_id',$doctors)->get();
        
    }
```

but i get the same name twice

Comment: [Take a look at eloquent relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships)

Comment: Did you have defined relation methods in your model files ?

Comment: The problem is that user_id and business_id are the same field in the user model

Comment: `user_id` and `business_id` both represents the id of the user table?? in that case who is client and who is doctor??

Comment: It is determined by user_type

Comment: then define two relationships in the appointment model. `client()` and `business()`. let me know if you want a detail answer.

Comment: I want to get two records from the users table 1 of the client and the business()

Comment: ya, check out @umi answer. that is what exactly you are looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming user_id and business_id are both representing the id of the user.

In that case :

```
# App/Models/Appointment.php

class Appointment 
{
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }

    public function business()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'business_id');
    }    
}
```

Documentation : [BelongsTo Relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one-defining-the-inverse-of-the-relationship)

Answer (score 1):

Just define relationship in model like:

In Appointment  model write:

```
public function user ()
{
    return $this->your-relationship(User::class);
}
```

For User:

```
public function appointment ()
{
    return $this->your-relationship(Appointment::class);
}
```

Comment: i defined it like this  public function user(){return $this->belongsToMany(User::class); } but it just gets the clients name not the doctors

Answer (score 1):

for example if you want to fetch the doctor you must fetch with user__type filtering.

```
//something like this
$x = $appointments->user()->where('user_type', 'doctor')->first();
$x->name;
```